# Text pushed offscreen after adding margin-left:10px;

Tags: css, text, padding

Something strange happens when I want to let my text begin at 10px margin from the left side in my right half of the "block" tag. When I add `margin-left: 10px;` suddenly all my text is gone. Any ideas what is causing this? And how I could fix this?

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="part">
        <div class="part halfleft">
            <p>
                <img alt="" src="src.png" style="width: 469px; height: 371px; " /></p>
        </div>
        <div class="part halfright">
            <h7> Title!</h7>
            <p>
                Sentence 1</p>
            <p>
                Sentence 2</p>
            <p>
                Sentence 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
    /*….*/
    #container h7 {
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 35px;    
        font-size: 30px;        
    }
    #container .part {
        width: 960px;
        height: 475px;
        background-color: #fff;
        float: left;
        text-align: left;   
    }   
    #container .part.halfleft {
        width: 480px;
        float: left;
        font-size: 16px;    
    }
    #container .part.halfright {
        width: 480px;
        float: left;
        padding-top: 30px;
        /*margin-left: 10px; or padding-left: 10px; pushes text off screen*/
        font-size: 16px;        
    }
```

Comment: Try making your width 470px and add the margin back in and see if that fixes it.  I would also suggest using padding in this case.

Comment: Thanks everybody for quick replies! Very logic of course!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your elements are floated, and with the extra 10px, they cannot fit side by side inside the container div.

A simple fix would be to remove 10px from one of the floated div's or 5px from both.

```
#container .part.halfright {
        width: 470px;
        float: left;
        padding-top: 30px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        font-size: 16px;        
}
```

**> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzDwA/) <**

Answer (score 1):

You are giving fixed width to the parent element and assigning float property to the child elements.

Here you are splitting up the width of the parent element between the child elements correctly and now if you add margin-left or margin-right (or padding) to your child elements then that child element will go down.

So, you can do two things here

- Decrease the width of the child element (based on the added margin/padding) or
- Do adjustments in your extra margin properties. (**+1-1 = 0**)

Something like this,

If you give `margin-left:10px;` then also give `margin-right:-10px` . This will keep equilibrium and doesn't effect the layout.

Answer (score 1):

You have in your **CSS**:

```
#container .part.halfright {
    width: 480px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 30px;
    /*margin-left: 10px; or padding-left: 10px; pushes text off screen*/
    font-size: 16px;        
};
```

**Width:480px** + **margin-left/padding-left:10px** = **490px** -> the container needs more space then **480px**.

So , put `width:470px`.

Or put on `#container .part` `width:970px;`.

Or `#container .part.halfright` `width:470px`.

And so on...

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t7bZz/1/).